# Check for new files in bucket and convert it into json

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket with list of CEF format files.So i will be converting these files to json using python and put it into a different bucket.This is a real streaming data,how can we detect the list of new files in bucket and is there any stream position key we can use to store the last point using python

Answer (score 0):

you could use the amazon aws SDK for python which can be found at  https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/

This can be done  by using the AWS SDK for Python (Boto3) to list the objects in the bucket and check the LastModified property of each object. If the LastModified property of an object is greater than a certain timestamp or date, then it is considered a new file.

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timezone

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket_name = 'my-bucket'

# Use the S3 bucket resource to get a list of all objects in the bucket
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
all_objects = bucket.objects.all()

# Define a timestamp cutoff for new files (e.g. 1 day ago)
cutoff_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(days=1)

# Loop through each object in the bucket and check its LastModified timestamp
for obj in all_objects:
    if obj.last_modified > cutoff_time:
        print(f"Found new file: {obj.key}")
```

then for storing the last position in the stream, you can use the S3 list_objects_v2 API with the ContinuationToken parameter to retrieve objects in batches and keep track of the last key processed

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
prefix = 'my-folder/'

# Set the initial ContinuationToken to None
continuation_token = None

# Keep looping until there are no more objects to retrieve
while True:
    # Use the list_objects_v2 API to retrieve a batch of objects
    response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix, ContinuationToken=continuation_token)

    # Loop through each object in the batch
    for obj in response['Contents']:
        # Process the object here
        print(f"Found object: {obj['Key']}")

    # Check if there are more objects to retrieve
    if response['IsTruncated']:
        # If there are more objects, set the ContinuationToken to the next marker
        continuation_token = response['NextContinuationToken']
    else:
        # If there are no more objects, break out of the loop
        break
```